# Can I use virtualization without grub crashes? Why does grub crashes after enabling BIOS virtualization?

Tags: grub2, virtualization

I have a dual Ubuntu/Windows PC. I installed VirtualBox on Windows OS but it didn't work. I read that I had to enable virtualization on the BIOS, so I did it. After that, grub didn't start. I tried to restore grub with supergrub2 without success. Tried with a live CD without success. Tried to reinstall Ubuntu 21.10... I couldn't.

So I went to BIOS to disable virtualization, and grub started correctly.

Comment: But I cannot use Virtualbox.

Comment: It's a problem with the firmware (UEFI). Updating it should be your first troubleshooting step. Even without the update you should perhaps check what other changes you be inadvertently making and/or whether the boot order isn't somehow changed by enabling virtualization (it shouldn't but you must check anyway and adjust accordingly). This has nothing to do with Ubuntu.